# Why I can't launch tensorboard

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cmd, tensorboard

These are my code for python3 but when it comes to cmd to launch the tensorboard, I can't access the tensorboard.

Putting my codes working correctly and I am using this command to run the tensorboard

```
tensorboard --logdir=path/to/log-directory
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey you have to put the directory properly not the placeholder .. ie not ‘path/to/log-directory’

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but it seems that TensorBoard works correctly. You have to specify the correct folder on your machine in which you store the events file, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorboard is working fine, you need to replace 'path / to / log-directory' for your folder where your summary is located.